# How to filter views with referring user?

Tags: picklist, lookup, user, list-view, filters

I am trying to create list Views.

I have 3 objects User, Object2 and Object3.
Object2 having lookup with user & object3 having lookup with Object2.

I save the object2 record with the user.

Object2 & object3  having same one picklist field with values ex: A,B,C .

I am looking to filter list view on 0bject3 as like below.

filter criteria: current user's.object2. picklist value.

How to achieve ?

Comment: I may miss something but why dont you create a formula field on obj 3 to get object2 picklist val. Then you can easily filter.

Comment: @erkan çipil, Good idea, But i don't want to change the value on object3 when object2 changes, I just want to filter the records based on the object2 value.